# Error in running simple Web application "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found"

Tags: asp.net

I tried to run this code but it raise an error at con.Open() method
"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found"

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = "server = (localdb)\v11.0 ;  database =     DepartmentsAndEmployees ; integrated security=true";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Employees", conn);
            conn.Open();            
            GridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();            
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it can not find the server. There is something wrong with your connection string.

Try this connection string builder:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/sql-connection-string/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx